# Glowing style effect

Tags: css

Is it possible to create glowing text like this 
[Flash Example](http://activeden.net/item/glowing-buttons-1/26650?WT.ac=category_thumb&WT.seg_1=category_thumb&WT.z_author=Webmarbles) in CSS?

I am try to find a solution but I can't find anything like this. Are there any tutorials to get this behavior? I found [this one](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/link-glow/index.html), but there is a big difference between them.

Comment: No, this is not possible without 1000+ lines of Javascript.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Thats incorrect as two answers show.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr comparing those 2 answers to the given Flash example he's trying to reproduce is akin to saying a Fiat Multipla is identical to a Ferrari because they can both drive you to the nearest supermarket. Reproducing the exact effect, or even something near to it, is simply impossible with the current state of CSS without thousands of lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Well although the example shows an animation of the glow affect, you could instead use a text-shadow on the hover selector in CSS.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="link">Link</li>    
        <li class="link">Link2</li>  
        <li class="link">Link3</li>  
    </ul>    
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    background-color:steelblue;
}

.link{
    font-size:2em;
}

.link:hover{
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(192, 192, 192, 1);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fRwGA/

Answer (score 0):

I am remiss to link to W3Schools, but I'm on a computer that doesn't have CSS3 capability at the moment.

You can get the kind of effect you need using [the `text-shadow` property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-shadow_neon). By giving the shadow a bright colour, rather than a dark one you can get a neon effect. You aren't going to be able to get the animation effect without javascript, but code to the effect of:

```
<a class='neon' href='http://example.com'>My cool effect</a>
```

With a corresponding CSS rule of:

```
a.neon:hover {
    text-shadow:0 0 3px #eaeaff
}
```

Should come close to the effect you need.

Comment: Why not link to MDN, then? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow

Comment: @minitech The W3Schools linked explicitly mentioned a 'neon' effect which is close to what the OP wants. And I couldn't test it... damn work PC :(